# POST form, then rediret to url

Tags: jquery

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to accomplish what I need. I have a list of anchor links and I want to submit/post a form (to the same page) first, and then redirect to the url when the user clicks on one of the links.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$("ul.sort li a").click(function(){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
event.preventDefault();

var form = $("#loc_form");
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.success) 
    {
      window.location = href;
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});   
});   
});  
</script>
```

I can't seem to get it to POST and send that data to the redirected url. I used html dataType and that just shows the entire html doc in the response.

Comment: You cannot get the `data` on the redirected page.

Comment: Trying to understand what you're doing here: Are you ajax post to form.action, waiting for a response to request #1, then redirecting to a.href for request #2 with the same data for both requests?

Comment: But I think this would all be easier if you posted the redirect url along with your other data in a standard form submission, then have the server return a redirect response with the url you sent with the form.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to post the data from the form to the url being redirect to

Comment: The redirect is GET so you'll have to send that data as parameters on the url.

Comment: Is POST not an option to send data to a redirected url? Using GET would complicate things and interfere with my permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your AJAX function is incorrect. Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form.serialize()   
 }).done(function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
      window.location = href;
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it doesn't seem like posting the data succeeds.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm assuming you're putting an external PHP file in the url parameter? Is the path set correctly? What's the file doing? With data.success means that file should be outputting an object named success back to the .done function. Is this being done? At the end of that file should be: $output['success'] = "success"; echo json_encode($output);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but the answer was far simpler than I realized. I didn't even need ajax for it.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("ul.sort li a").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var form = $("#loc_form");
    form.attr('action', href)
    form.submit();
 });   
});
```

This successfully posts the data and redirects the page accordingly.